# event.preventDefault() works in one case but not other

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have two forms on my page, one for submitting a comment and another for voting in a poll. These two functions are just a couple dozen lines apart but only the one for #comment-form actually prevents the default. The #poll-form submit button refreshes the page which is not what I want it to do.

```
$("#comment-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    addComment();
});

//ajax stuff for adding the comment, addComment() etc.

$("#poll-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    castVote();
});
```

HTML looks like:

```
<div class="add-comment">
  <form id="comment-form">
    <textarea id="comment-content" name="comment" placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="poll">
  <h1 class="title">Poll</h1>
  <h3>Poll Question</h3>
    <form id="poll-form">
      <input type="radio" name="vote" value="0">
      Choice 1
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1">
      Choice 2
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="vote" value="2"> 
      Choice 3
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="vote" value="3">
      Choice 4
      <br>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I can't see the difference or figure out why the #poll-form submit won't prevent default.

Comment: nothing wrong with the code, may be your `castVote();` function is reloading. check the function

Comment: I copied your code and .preventDefault() is working for me in both cases. Maybe reload comes from the `castVote();`

Comment: try your own code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syamsoul/mwL78sah/ .... and there's nothing wrong with your code...

Comment: Make sure you do not have duplicate ids in your code `console.assert($('[id="poll-form"]') === 1)` just before you add event listener.

Comment: If your form is dynamic use this code `$(document).on("submit", "#poll-form", 'function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    castVote();
});`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this also for stop form submit,

```
$("#poll-form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('it works!');
  return  false;
});
```

Comment: Why should that make a difference? There's no reason `preventDefault()` shouldn't work. I can't think of any circumstance where `return false` would work and `preventDefault()` would not. Three people have already said, in comments, that they can't reproduce the problem.